# How best to add tracking scripts to your site

Tags: javascript, magento, analytics

We are adding **Quantast** tracking pixels/scripts to our site.  They are unique for each page.

We have a book an appointment page and we have a script to be added to the form page and another to the form success page.  The issue is their is no page reload when the user submits the form successfully, the form is submitted via ajax and the success message is loaded with out reloading the entire page.

I could remove & add the correct tracking script with JS but will this have an effect on how the tracking script works?  Does the script need to be on the page before the load event?

BTW, it's a Magento site.  I'm adding the rest of the scripts before the closing body tag from within a Magento template file.

Below is an example of a tracking script.

```
<!-- Start Quantcast Tag -->
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var _qevents = _qevents || [];

(function() {
var elem = document.createElement('script');
elem.src = (document.location.protocol == "https:" ? "https://secure" : "http://edge") + ".quantserve.com/quant.js";
elem.async = true;
elem.type = "text/javascript";
var scpt = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
scpt.parentNode.insertBefore(elem, scpt);
})();

_qevents.push(
{qacct:"k-i3N??????????G",labels:"_fp.event.Booking Success"}
);
</script>
<noscript>
<img src="//pixel.quantserve.com/pixel/k-i3N??????????G.gif?labels=_fp.event.Booking+Success" style="display: none;" border="0" height="1" width="1" alt="Quantcast"/>
</noscript>
<!-- End Quantcast tag -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you add this:

```
_qevents.push(
{qacct:"k-i3N??????????G",labels:"_fp.event.Homepage"}
);
</script>
<noscript>
<img src="//pixel.quantserve.com/pixel/k-i3N??????????G.gif?labels=_fp.event.Homepage" style="display: none;" border="0" height="1" width="1" alt="Quantcast"/>
</noscript>
```

in your form success page you should be good to go